# How can I correct these issues when building Epson scanner drivers?

Tags: linux, makefile, build, driver, epson

I am trying to get an Epson V30 scanner working under Gentoo Linux.
To that end, I downloaded and attempted to build the drivers from their website:
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

As per the readme, I run `./configure` before running `make`. However `make check` reveals problems:

```
make[3]: *** No rule to make target '../libimage-stream.la', needed by 'test-pcx'.  Stop.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/james/Downloads/iscan_extract/iscan-2.30.4/lib/tests'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:588: check-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/james/Downloads/iscan_extract/iscan-2.30.4/lib/tests'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:552: check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/james/Downloads/iscan_extract/iscan-2.30.4/lib'
make: *** [Makefile:448: check-recursive] Error 1
```

I tried finding out where to get this `libimage-stream.la` but no luck:

```
~/Downloads/iscan_extract/iscan-2.30.4  
└✸Mon,Jul17@16:52:~$ e-file libimage-stream   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python-exec/python3.11/e-file", line 36, in <module>
    if len(files['result']) > 0:
           ~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'result'
```

If I just go ahead and do make, I get different errors, IDK if they are related to the problem identified by `make check` or are something else I will need to deal with.

Any assistance in getting these drivers to build would be welcome.

Comment: Did running `configure` report any errors?

Comment: No. However I managed to achieve my general purpose by installing some drivers from the repository (media-gfx/iscan-plugin-gt-f720) as well as building the `iscan-data` package without the `udev` flag. I was only trying to build the drivers because that had failed previously (ie with the udev flag).